# How to get specific XML tag values?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

Is there any way to get the specific values of an XML tag?

```
<Country Rank="0">
  <Name>xyz</Name>
  <Place>abcd</IntValue>
 </Country>
<Country Rank="1">
  <Name>xyz1</Name>
  <Place>abcd1</IntValue>
 </Country>
<Country Rank="2">
  <Name>xyz2</Name>
  <Place>abcd2</IntValue>
 </Country>
```

How can I get the place of a country of particular rank?

Below code results the text of all XML tags. But I need to traverse through specific xpaths.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('file.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

for node in tree.iter():
    print node.tag
    print node.text
```

Comment: I have removed the explicitly off-topic part of your question. The rest seems a lot like a request for code - this isn't a code-writing service. Please show a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt to implement this, and precisely describe the problems with it.

Comment: @  jonrsharpe : Edited with minimal example. Please help me out.

Comment: *"... and precisely describe the problems with it"*.

Comment: So, here how can i fetch the values like abcd2, abcd1 etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

Using [XPaths](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath):

```
[place.text for country in e.findall(".//Country[@Rank='1']") for place in country.iter("Place")]
```

Where `e` is your tree or element root. The rank value in the Xpath `".//Country[@Rank='1']"` can be used to change the desired rank, so you can make a function like:

```
def get_places_by_rank(e, rank):
    xpath = ".//Country[@Rank='{}']".format(rank)
    return [place.text for country in e.findall(xpath) for place in country.iter("Place")]
```

And use it like:

```
>>> e=ET.fromstring("""
... <Countries>
...     <Country Rank="0">
...         <Name>xyz</Name>
...         <Place>abcd</Place>
...     </Country>
...     <Country Rank="1">
...         <Name>xyz1</Name>
...         <Place>abcd1</Place>
...     </Country>
...     <Country Rank="2">
...         <Name>xyz2</Name>
...         <Place>abcd2</Place>
...     </Country>
...  </Countries>""")
>>>
>>> get_places_by_rank(e, 1)
['abcd1']
>>> get_places_by_rank(e, 2)
['abcd2']
>>> get_places_by_rank(e, 3)
[]
>>> get_places_by_rank(e, 0)
['abcd']
```